# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: domain.ShoppingCart$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, cdi, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting a weird error, i'm not able to debug. I'll be obliged if you can go through the details and suggest me something my friends.

I'm using Jboss Server 7.1.

Web App working fine for all modules. But when I'm done with products in Cart, and do "Checkout", then it cause the exception.

I provided almost all the required information, Please if you need anything else let me know. I'd really appreciate your kind responses. Thanks a lot viewing my request.

**Libraries i Included in the Project** ( Except JBoss own included Libraries )

[image: Libraries]

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try{
            Configuration conf=new Configuration();
            conf.configure("/com/webshop/hb/config/mycfg-mysql.xml");
             sessionFactory =conf.buildSessionFactory(); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return sessionFactory;
}
```

**ShoppingCart.java**

```
package domain;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@SessionScoped
@Entity
public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable { private static long currentId =1;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="date")
    private Date date;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    private User user;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Product, Integer> orders = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();

    @Column(name="status")
    private OrderStatus status; // String 

    public ShoppingCart() {
        this(new Date());
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Date date) {
        super();
        this.id = currentId++; // Simple way of getting an unique id. To be deferred to the DBMS later.
        this.date = date;
        this.status = OrderStatus.EMPTY;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Date date, User user) {
        this(date);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Date date, User user, OrderStatus status) {
        this(date, user);
        if (((status == OrderStatus.COMPLETED) || (status == OrderStatus.PAID)) && (this.getUser() == null)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No user specified for complete or paid orders");
        }
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Map<Product, Integer> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Map<Product, Integer> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public OrderStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setCompleted(OrderStatus status) throws IllegalStateTransitionException {
        if ((status == OrderStatus.COMPLETED) && (this.getUser() == null)) {
            throw new IllegalStateTransitionException(this.getStatus().toString(), OrderStatus.COMPLETED.toString(), "Customer empty");
        }
        if ((status == OrderStatus.PAID) && (this.getUser() == null)) {
            throw new IllegalStateTransitionException(this.getStatus().toString(), OrderStatus.PAID.toString(), "Customer empty");
        }
        if ((status == OrderStatus.PAID) && (this.getStatus() != OrderStatus.COMPLETED)) {
            throw new IllegalStateTransitionException(this.getStatus().toString(), OrderStatus.PAID.toString(), "Can only go to paid for completed orders");
        }
        this.status = status;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addToCart(Product product, int amountSelected) {
        if (orders.containsKey(product)) {
            int amount = orders.get(product);
            amount +=amountSelected;
            orders.put(product, amount);
        }
        else {
            orders.put(product, amountSelected);
        }
    }

    public void removeFromCart(Product product) {
        if (orders.containsKey(product)) {
            int amount = orders.get(product);
            amount --;
            if (amount <= 0) {
                orders.remove(product);
            }
            else {
                orders.put(product, amount);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getNumberOfItems() {
        Set<Product> uniqueProducts = orders.keySet();
        int amount = 0;
        for (Product aProduct: uniqueProducts) {
            amount += orders.get(aProduct);
        }
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        return "Order of " + this.user + ", date " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

**mycfg-mysql.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <!-- <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property> -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
 -->
   <property name="connection.datasource">java:jboss/datasources/webshopstudent</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">100</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <!-- Automatic schema creation (begin) === -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
   <mapping class="domain.User"/>
  <mapping class="domain.Product"/>
   <mapping class="domain.Wax"/>
  <mapping class="domain.Miscellaneous"/>
  <mapping class="domain.Honey"/>
  <mapping class="domain.Flower"/>
  <mapping class="domain.ShoppingCart"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Exception I'm getting when I Checkout from Cart**

[image]

**Function which is causing the Issue**

```
public String confirmOrder() throws IllegalStateTransitionException {

        shoppingcart.setUser(userholder.getCurrentUser());
        shoppingcart.setCompleted(OrderStatus.COMPLETED);
        shoppingcart.setDate(new Date());

        // Setting up sessions

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(shoppingcart); // This Line is causing the Exception, I checked by debugging
        session.close();

        updateStocks();

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        fc.getELContext().getELResolver().setValue(fc.getELContext(), null, "shoppingCart", null);

        //printing Invoice

        //writing to file
        try {
            String content = "Customer Name: " + shoppingcart.getUser().firstName + " " + shoppingcart.getUser().lastName +"\r\n" + 
                             "Address : " + shippingAddress + "\r\n" +
                             "Date Received: " + shoppingcart.getDate() + "\r\n" +
                             "Order Items :" + shoppingcart.getOrders() + "\r\n" +
                             "Money to be received :" + productHolder.subTotal(); 
//          File file = new File("/Users/Vinod/Documents/newfile.txt");
            File file = new File("F:/" + shoppingcart.getId() + shoppingcart.getUser().firstName + "invoice.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        return "orderComplete";

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the reason is pretty obvious: your `ShoppingCart` entity is also a CDI managed bean. I'm almost sure that you are injecting `shoppingcart` somewhere above the method `confirmOrder`:

```
@Inject
ShoppingCart shoppingcart;
```

Am I right? If yes, then this is the cause.

Generally JPA entities [shouldn't be managed](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WhyIsVetoABestPracticeForPersistentJPAEntities.html) as a CDI Beans. The reasoning behind this is to prevent the BeanManager to perform operations that may cause the JPA provider to break (as this caused your exception).

So please try something like this:

```
package domain;

@Entity
public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable {
     // ...
}
```

Then define another class, that holds the above entity:

```
package com.some_package;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ShoppingCartWrapper {

     ShoppingCart store = new ShoppingCart(); // this is your entity
}
```

This class can be injected wherever you want. And then saving will look like:

```
public String confirmOrder() throws IllegalStateTransitionException {

      // ...
      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      session.beginTransaction();
      session.save(shoppingCartWrapper.getStore()); 
      session.close();
      // ...
}
```

BTW: personal tip: managing transactions like this - I mean "by hand", without interceptors is **error-prone** and doesn't make your code **clean**.